# When not collapsed some part of the the toolbar is visible over the ImageView of CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

The CollapsingToolbarView works perfectly fine, but there is this unwanted strip on the ImageView of the collapsing toolbar.

As you can see below there is a red strip (possibly toolbar) after the status bar. How do I get rid of it?

[image: screenshot1]      [image: screenshot2]

Below is the relevant xml file:

fragment_movie.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.jayeshsolanki.mmdb.ui.fragment.MovieFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_movie"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:title="@string/placeholder_movie_item_title">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop_movie"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                tools:src="@drawable/placeholder_movie_item_backdrop"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_movie"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The theme for the parent activity is set as `"@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` in the Manifest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` is supposed to be on `CoordinatorLayout`, `AppBarLayout`, `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and the `ImageView` inside it.

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem. Also removing `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from `CoordinatorLayout` works and this looks as same as setting it in `CoordinatorLayout`, `AppBarLayout`, `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, `ImageView`. Can you tell me why do I need to use it for all these views?

Comment: @jayeshsolanki93 Frankly, to this day I haven't found a satisfactory answer to that question. Normally it's used so that your content is not drawn beneath translucent status and navigation bar. Classes from `design` support library however built some special behavior around this in conjunction with `android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds` (I think).

Comment: Tip: `CollapsingToolbarLayout` sets its `fitsSystemWindows` internally depending on the parent `AppBarLayout`'s value. You don't have to set it in XML (although it doesn't hurt)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing adjustViewBounds attribute from image. You're using centerCrop which should be enough for image to show properly and fill all space. By adjusting view bounds you're preserving aspect ratio, so the image doesn't fill the app bar space.

Comment: Tried that, it did not help.

Comment: Tried moving your recycler view top after the app bar layout?